# JSON with jq, change all values to *

Tags: bash, json, jq

I need to replace every value in a JSON file with a * and then return the output to a new JSON file.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Global": {
    "Version": "1.0.0",
    "Environment": {
      "Long": "Local",
      "Short": "loc"
    },
    "ActiveDirectory": {
      "Role": {
        "User": "user",
        "Manager": "manager",
        "Admin": "admin"
      }
    },
    "Jwt": {
      "Authority": "http://localost:8089/auth/reals/master",
      "Audience": "pneumanet-client",
      "AuthorizationUrl": "http://localost:8089/auth/reals/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
      "TokenUrl": "http://localost:8089/auth/reals/master/protocol/openid-connect/token",
      "Real": "master"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see all the keys that have a value like "Default": "Information" I would like to change "Information" to a *. This has to be applied to all key value fields. Is this possible with jq, because I can't figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear whether you need to set all keys that have the value `Information`, or all `Default` keys that have the value `Information`. One could interpret "apply to all key-value fields" to mean any `Default` key under any key-value field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way would be to use recursive descent (`..`) and select nodes with value `"Information"` and update them:

```
$ jq '(.. | select(. == "Information")) |= "*"' file.json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "*",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "*"
    }
  },
  "Global": {
    "Version": "1.0.0",
    "Environment": {
      "Long": "Local",
      "Short": "loc"
    },
    "ActiveDirectory": {
      "Role": {
        "User": "user",
        "Manager": "manager",
        "Admin": "admin"
      }
    },
    "Jwt": {
      "Authority": "http://localost:8089/auth/reals/master",
      "Audience": "pneumanet-client",
      "AuthorizationUrl": "http://localost:8089/auth/reals/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
      "TokenUrl": "http://localost:8089/auth/reals/master/protocol/openid-connect/token",
      "Real": "master"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you need to restrict it to the `Default` keys: `jq '(.. | select(.Default? == "Information").Default) |= "*"' file`

Comment: @Kusalananda thank you - I can see now that the question is ambiguous

Comment: I noticed the question is a bit unclear. What I need is a way to change all values into a *. Not just Default, but all values. I hope this clears things out. Maybe jq isn't the right tool for this and should I check a regex. But I was wondering if it would be possible.

Comment: @Alex that's possibly made it even less clear - do you mean literally **all** (leaf - presumably string) values, regardless of both the key and value? If so, you could simplify to `jq '(.. | strings) |= "*"'`. It might help if you were to edit your question with a minimal complete example i.e. both input **and** expected output.

Comment: @steeldriver this is exactly what I needed thanks!